# Conecting MQTT server from Meteor Galaxy

Tags: meteor, mqtt

My application uses the perak/meteor-mqtt-collection package to connect to an MQTT server running on IP XX.XX.XX.XXX. Locally it works fine, but on galaxy it doesn't. It just doesn't seem to be connected to the MQTT server. Do I need any particular configuration to connect to another server?

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  let server = "mqtt://XX.XX.XX.XXX";  
...
  Events.mqttConnect(server, arrayTags, { insert: true });

});
```